# Accessing all Buttons to Dynamically to set the OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

I have found many questions relating to dynamically **creating** `buttons` and at the same time, setting the `OnClickListener` for each but I have a different problem.

I am making a game which uses buttons (77 of them to be exact) and I have created all of them in the `XML` page.

Having all of them **already** created, I am looking for a **working** way to set all of the `OnClickListeners` for these buttons. So far I have tried using [this](http://android-wtf.com/2013/06/how-to-easily-traverse-any-view-hierarchy-in-android/#comment-5441) method, and it crashes while "Traversing" the `ViewGroup root` in **this** code:

```
private void setupMap() {
    LayoutTraverser.build(new LayoutTraverser.Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(View v) {
            Log.e("c.getTag()", v.getTag().toString());
            if(v.getTag()!=null){
                int t = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
                if (t >= 1 && t <= 77){
                    v.setBackgroundResource(Integer.parseInt(callRandomTarget().toString()));
                    v.setOnClickListener(SharpShooterActivity.this);
                }
            }
        }
    }).traverse(root);
}
```

and here is what I set `root` to:

```
root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

I have Logged `root.toString()+" "i+" "+root.getChildCount()` in the `LayoutTraverser` class and this is what it returns:

```
08-20 08:59:54.508: E/root count(24059): android.widget.FrameLayout{42f977f8 V.E..... ........ 0,195-1920,1080 #1020002 android:id/content} 0 1
08-20 08:59:54.508: D/AndroidRuntime(24059): Shutting down VM
08-20 08:59:54.508: W/dalvikvm(24059): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41beeda0)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059): Process: com.killmario, PID: 24059
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.killmario.SharpShooterActivity$1.process(SharpShooterActivity.java:76)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.killmario.LayoutTraverser.traverse(LayoutTraverser.java:28)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.killmario.SharpShooterActivity.setupMap(SharpShooterActivity.java:85)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.killmario.SharpShooterActivity.onClick(SharpShooterActivity.java:151)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-20 08:59:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I understand I am getting a `NPE` here. What I don't understand is if what I am trying to do is even possible or maybe I am just missing something silly, like setting `root` equal to the wrong thing.

I'm open to any different ways to go about doing this but it needs to happen dynamically, as I will have to implement the `OnClick()` function dynamically as well but the `OnClickListener` is my only issue.

Thanks,

Darrell

**UPDATE**

`XML`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.killmario.SharpShooterActivity"
    tools:ignore="TooManyViews" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/acceptButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
        android:tag="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button04"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/acceptButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/acceptButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/acceptButton"
        android:tag="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button04"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button04"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button04"
        android:tag="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button03"
        android:tag="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:tag="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button08"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button02"
        android:tag="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button07"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button08"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button08"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button08"
        android:tag="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button06"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button07"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button07"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button07"
        android:tag="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button05"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button06"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button06"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button06"
        android:tag="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button09"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button05"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button05"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button05"
        android:tag="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button10"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button09"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button09"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button09"
        android:tag="11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button13"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/acceptButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/acceptButton"
        android:tag="12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button15"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button13"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button13"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button13"
        android:tag="13" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button17"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button04"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button03"
        android:tag="14" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button19"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button04"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button04"
        android:tag="15" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button21"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button08"
        android:tag="16" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button20"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button08"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button07"
        android:tag="17" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button14"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button08"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button08"
        android:tag="18" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button16"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button06"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button05"
        android:tag="19" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button11"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button05"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button05"
        android:tag="20" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button18"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button05"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button05"
        android:tag="21" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button12"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button10"
        android:tag="22" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button41"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button15"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button40"
        android:tag="24" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button22"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button41"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button41"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button41"
        android:tag="25" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button40"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button41"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button41"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button13"
        android:tag="23" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button43"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button22"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button22"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button22"
        android:tag="26" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button42"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button43"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button43"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button20"
        android:tag="27" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button31"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button42"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button42"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button20"
        android:tag="28" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button29"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button14"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button16"
        android:tag="29" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button27"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button14"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button14"
        android:tag="30" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button25"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button11"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button18"
        android:tag="31" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button23"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button11"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button11"
        android:tag="32" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button39"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button12"
        android:tag="33" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button34"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button32"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button32"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button32"
        android:tag="34" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button30"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button41"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button32"
        android:tag="36" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button32"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button41"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button22"
        android:tag="35" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button26"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button43"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button42"
        android:tag="37" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button36"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button26"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button26"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button31"
        android:tag="38" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button38"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button31"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button29"
        android:tag="39" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button35"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button29"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button27"
        android:tag="40" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button28"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button27"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button25"
        android:tag="41" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button37"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button25"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button25"
        android:tag="42" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button24"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button37"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button37"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button39"
        android:tag="43" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button33"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button24"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button24"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button39"
        android:tag="44" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button54"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button61"
        android:tag="56" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button44"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button34"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button34"
        android:tag="45" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button63"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button44"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button44"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button44"
        android:tag="46" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button62"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button63"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button63"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button26"
        android:tag="47" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button65"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button62"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button62"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button36"
        android:tag="48" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button64"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button26"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button26"
        android:tag="49" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button53"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button36"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button36"
        android:tag="50" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button51"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button35"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button28"
        android:tag="51" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button49"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button35"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button35"
        android:tag="52" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button47"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button37"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button24"
        android:tag="53" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button45"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button24"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button33"
        android:tag="54" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button61"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button33"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button33"
        android:tag="55" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button56"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button44"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button54"
        android:tag="57" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button52"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button56"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button56"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button65"
        android:tag="58" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button48"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button52"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button52"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button52"
        android:tag="59" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button58"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button65"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button65"
        android:tag="60" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button60"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button53"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button51"
        android:tag="61" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button57"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button51"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button49"
        android:tag="62" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button50"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button57"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button57"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button57"
        android:tag="63" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button59"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button49"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button49"
        android:tag="64" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button46"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button59"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button59"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button61"
        android:tag="65" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button55"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button46"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button46"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button46"
        android:tag="66" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button73"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button56"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button52"
        android:tag="68" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button67"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button56"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button56"
        android:tag="67" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button74"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button56"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button56"
        android:tag="69" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button66"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button74"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button74"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button58"
        android:tag="70" />
```

**LIMIT REACHED**

You get the gist of it...

Comment: are you sure you set the tag?

Comment: I will update the Q and show you...

Comment: hv u wriiten on click lister in SharpShooterActivity?

Comment: The entire question is how can I dynamically set the OnClickListener for these buttons...

Comment: the log prints  `FrameLayout` but your root is a `RelativeLayout`. Now if the `RelativeLayout` is added to the content, when the traversal meets it, you'll get the NPE because it has not a tag

Comment: How can I fix that issue?

Comment: Finally understand what you were referring to... I have now set tags to everything in the xml doc. I will try and see if it worked now (Crossing fingers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @blackbelt noted, I was missing the `tag` for the `<RelativeLayout>`. Once this was added, **see below**, the error was gone.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:tag="11000"
    tools:context="com.killmario.SharpShooterActivity"
    tools:ignore="TooManyViews" >
```

This error occured when the `Traverser` tried to get the `Tag`, and `RelativeLayout` did not have one.